# The Status Bar of Android Project can not change color

Tags: android, kotlin, statusbar

Here's my `themes.xml`

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ColorMyViews" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#BE19FF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#a100e0</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

The Status Bar color is not changing no matter what I try!
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status bar color is based on the `colorPrimaryDark` value of the current theme.

```
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">????</item>
```

Comment: Wait do you mean colorPrimaryVariant? That's the only thing I have.

Comment: No, add that tag to your theme

Answer (score 2):

Oh! I found out how to do it. You add this line to the bottom of the theme:
`<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>`

That's because I'm using the latest Android Studio Version.